# How to model this rails relationship, "has two"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, model-associations

Imagine a roster of characters in a game.

I need to let users vote on which character counters which character and be able to save that in the database.

`Batman is strong against Superman`

`Batman is strong against Joker`

`Batman is weak against The Riddler`

---

How can I model this relationship between two of the same type of models? `Batman, Superman and Joker` are all part of the same Model type `Superhero`.

If I were to create this same system on something like ASP.Net MVC, I would create a table called `Counterpicks` and have two fields `source_id` and `target_id` as int fields and use them as foreign keys towards the `Superhero` table. Do I need to create a `Counterpick` model in RoR?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the paragraph on Self Joins in [A Guide to Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins) (Rails Guides). What you need is also a self join.

The difference between your case and the example on Rails Guides is that you need a many-to-many relationship inside the `Superhero` model, while the example shows a `has_many` type of relationship.

Both kinds of many-to-many associations in Rails (`has_and_belongs_to_many` and `has_many through`) need a join table in the database. The `Counterpicks` table you mentioned is precisely a join table.

In your case it's going to end up looking a bit like this:

```
class Superhero < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :losers, :class_name => "Superhero", :foreign_key => "winner_id"
  has_and_belongs_to_many :winners, :class_name => "Superhero", :foreign_key => "loser_id"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your proposed table model and use the foreign key. Have a look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many